# How do you create remote project dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle

So in Maven one of the things you can do is create a project that dynamically downloads a bunch of other projects and uses them as components for the local build.

How is this done in Gradle? I can use it to pull down my custom tasks and build them automagically. Our build is huge and monolithic. Some break-down would be a good thing, also.

Comment: > *components for the local build* Do you mean dependencies? Or are you  talking about abstracting away build logic in other projects and them importing them into your build script? BTW, custom plugins is one way to apply a library of custom tasks to any project.

Comment: I mean dependencies that need to be downloaded and built and then the artifacts used as libraries. So projects as sub-projects that are not in the same source control.

Comment: Download source and build? Why would you not just get a pre-built binary from a maven like repo?

Comment: Perhaps because in some cases you want to work on the whole thing and in others you just want to work on components. For example you might have some changes to make to a component that talks to another component, but the changes are not to the interface between them. That is one case but the other is where you have to work on both or where you have to work on several. If the components are sizable and complex, then you might want to keep them separate as a division of labor. Then there's the case where CM will not permit write access to the maven repo except as part of a release.

Comment: The gradle way to do this is to create all the inter-related projects as subprojects under a root project. But that way, the projects are likely under the same source repo, and cloned/checked-out together [See here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) for more information.

Comment: The general impression I am getting is that Gradle is not often used for huge projects.

Comment: It is - at the very least, Gradle is suitable everywhere where maven is. The relationship between projects is usually to depend on binaries+version, not source, Decoupling projects like that is good abstraction anyway, regardless of Gradle.

Comment: The way your question is posed, it might help  if you can show the maven way to do something and ask for the Gradle equivalent.